# Оптимизация SQL запроса или денормализация?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Проблема кроется в том, что запрос к БД выполняется крайне долго (до 400 мс)

```
    SELECT * FROM production_category AS cc
        INNER JOIN LATERAL (
            SELECT cc.id AS id, SUM(products) AS p_count FROM (
                SELECT cc.id AS parent_id, category_id, COUNT(id) AS products FROM production_product_categories WHERE category_id IN (
                    SELECT id FROM production_category WHERE lft <= cc.rght AND lft >= cc.lft AND tree_id = cc.tree_id)
                    AND product_id IN ( SELECT id FROM production_product WHERE manufacturer_id = 15 )
                    GROUP BY category_id
                ) AS sub_cc
            GROUP BY parent_id ) AS cp USING(id)
    WHERE cp.p_count > 0;
```

Структура следующая:

Есть производитель (manufacturer), его продукция (production_product) и любой товар может быть в одной или нескольких категориях (production_category). Также могут быть категории, в которых нет товаров данного производителя.

Задача стоит сделать выборку категорий, в которых есть товары данного производителя.

Вот и возникает вопрос: или я перемудрил с запросом, или следует денормализовать базу и хранить информацию о категориях для производителя в отдельной таблице (точноее relationship (manufacturer_id, category_id)).

Postgresql (9.3.4)

```
     Nested Loop  (cost=207.57..129375.37 rows=42 width=223)
       ->  Seq Scan on production_category cc  (cost=0.00..25.20 rows=620 width=191)
       ->  Subquery Scan on cp  (cost=207.57..208.62 rows=1 width=36)
             Filter: (cc.id = cp.id)
             ->  HashAggregate  (cost=207.57..208.09 rows=42 width=12)
                   Filter: (sum((count(production_product_categories.id))) > 0::numeric)
                   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=206.41..206.83 rows=42 width=8)
                         ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=9.23..206.20 rows=42 width=8)
                               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.94..106.81 rows=45 width=12)
                                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on production_category  (cost=4.31..12.78 rows=1 width=4)
                                           Recheck Cond: ((lft <= cc.rght) AND (lft >= cc.lft))
                                           Filter: (tree_id = cc.tree_id)
                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on production_category_caf7cc51  (cost=0.00..4.31 rows=3 width=0)
                                                 Index Cond: ((lft <= cc.rght) AND (lft >= cc.lft))
                                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on production_product_categories  (cost=4.64..93.58 rows=45 width=12)
                                           Recheck Cond: (category_id = production_category.id)
                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on production_product_categories_b583a629  (cost=0.00..4.62 rows=45 width=0)
                                                 Index Cond: (category_id = production_category.id)
                               ->  Index Scan using production_product_pkey on production_product  (cost=0.29..2.20 rows=1 width=4)
                                     Index Cond: (id = production_product_categories.product_id)
                                     Filter: (manufacturer_id = 15)
```

Comment: `SELECT id FROM production_category WHERE lft <= cc.rght AND lft >= cc.lft` <- уоооооу, у вас там ещё и nested sets.

Comment: Nested Loop  (cost=207.57..129375.37 rows=42 width=223)
           ->  Seq Scan on production_category cc  (cost=0.00..25.20 rows=620 width=191) и т.д.

Comment: Я про структуру категорий. А если уж выкладывать план запроса, то тогда уж целиком и в вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: Вообще вся эта каша была придумана для того, чтобы воткнуть красиво в django rawqueryset и дальше работать с объектами. Кажется промахнулся.

Comment: План запроса добавил

Comment: А что такое p_count он же считается как количество товаро-категорий т.е. если товар в двух категориях то и даст число 2. Редко в работе нужны такие странные показатели, я бы понял если бы было например количество товаров. Вообще довольно сложно понять что и для чего тут выбирается. Вы би таблицы с образцами данных на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com привели, было бы проще. Думаю тут найдется что оптимизировать, для начала было бы неплохо избавится от lateral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд не плохой результат (около 100 мс) при следующем запросе:

```
SELECT cat.*
FROM production_category cat
WHERE cat.tree_id IN (
    SELECT 
        pc.tree_id
    FROM
        production_category pc
        INNER JOIN public.production_product_categories ppc ON (pc.id = ppc.category_id)
        INNER JOIN public.production_product pp ON (ppc.product_id = pp.id)
    WHERE
        pp.manufacturer_id = 15
    GROUP BY
        pc.id
) AND cat.parent_id IS NULL
ORDER BY cat.name;
```

Полагаю лучше тяжело сделать одним запросом.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, должно быть что-то в этом роде:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM production_category c 
INNER JOIN production_product_categories pc ON pc.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN production_product p ON p.id = pc.product_id
WHERE p.manufacturer_id = 15
```

Жаль, проверить сейчас не на чем.

Comment: Ну, тут как минимум потерян тот факт, что у ТС категории в nested sets, и вы выбираете только непосредственные категории, но не их надкатегории. Но идея, на мой взгляд, в верном направлении :) И вообще не факт, что ТСу надкатегории нужны, но это уже другое дело.

Comment: Нужны категории определенного уровня. Допустим категория для верхнего уровня есть категории светильники и шинопроводы. Но если захожу в категорию светильники, то нужны категории, у которых parent_id - id Светильников

Comment: @KamoPetrosyan в вопросе об этом ни слова, и в запрос id выбранной категории не передаётся.